# Connecting to host by SSH client in Linux by proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

I am really struggling with this.

> My host (A) is behind a proxy/firewall (PF) and needs to connect to
>   host H.

The proxy has HTTP/FTP/SOCK proxy configured and I have no issue to configure in web browser, wget etc.

But when I use...

```
ssh H //to connect my host
```

I have no success to pass over the proxy. It seems to try to connect directly instead of going via the PF.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ssh` has no native `SOCKS` client support, you need to use a `ProxyCommand` for that, for instance with `socat`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - SOCKS4A:myproxy:%h:%p,socksuser=nobody' user@host
```

Or use things like `tsocks` or `dante`'s `socksify` to transparently use SOCKS for TCP traffic.

For SOCKS5 with `socat` 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "SOCKS5:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:1080"' user@host
```

For HTTP Proxy `CONNECT` method with `socat` 2:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "PROXY:%h:%p|tcp:myproxy:80"' user@host
```

Comment: Awesome!! The socat SOCKS4A was the one that worked for me. I needed to clone a git repository behind a proxy into a corporate VPN. I created my socks proxy to the machine that's connected to the VPN (ssh -D 9999), then configured the client's SSH config to connect to the behindfirewall.corporate.com by using the socat command as the ProxyCommand into the SOCKS proxy host. The SOCKS4A also uses the proxy server  to resolve DNS which was a problem with other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) or [Proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/) (and be aware that tunnelling SSH through a proxy be forbidden by local policies in some networks).

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP Proxy CONNECT method with `socat`,

ProxyCommand: `socat - PROXY:myproxy:%h:%p,proxyport=myproxyport`