# What is a Linux alternative to SVL Header Injector and HTTP Injector?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I want to bypass the ISP's firewall, and succesfully did it on [Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/svlheaderinjector/) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.injector&hl=en_US) by sending a set of HTTP headers and using CONNECT method to establish an SSH connection to a remote ([example](https://cyberssh.com/)) SSH server.

```
POST http://host.com/ HTTP/1.0[crlf][crlf]
CONNECT host.com@[host_port] [protocol][crlf][crlf]
```

Then I use that connection as a SOCKS5 proxy, and become free of restrictions, imposed by ISP.

Now I want to do same on Linux, but I can't find any Linux alternative, and my laptop is pretty weak to have VirtualBox running all the time. Any suggestions? I get that there's probably no nice GUI for this, but I'm not afraid of console

Comment: no it does not help, I have NO control over the remote host whatsoever

Comment: Who said anything about needing control over the remote host? I've written an answer that expands on one of the suggestions there.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed duplicate, [Connecting to host by SSH client in Linux by proxy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68826/connecting-to-host-by-ssh-client-in-linux-by-proxy) provides almost an exact solution to your requirement. Adjusting it slightly gets these two solutions that work for me through a Squid proxy (one that's modified to allow tunneling to port 22, mind),

First up, install the appropriate package for the [ProxyTunnel](https://proxytunnel.sourceforge.io/usage.php) tool. On Debian/Raspbian it's "proxytunnel"

Now you can connect straight through with ssh via the `HTTP CONNECT` proxy and on to the target device

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='proxytunnel -p proxyHost:proxyPort -d %h:%p' user@remoteHost
```

If you are going to connect to `remoteHost` regularly, consider adding an entry in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host remoteHost
    ProxyCommand proxytunnel -p proxyHost:proxyPort -d %h:%p
```

On Cygwin (Windows) there is a different package, "connect-proxy" with slightly different syntax

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='connect-proxy -d -H proxyHost:proxyPort %h %p' user@remoteHost
```

And

```
Host remoteHost
    ProxyCommand connect-proxy -d -H proxyHost:proxyPort %h %p
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? if the provider gives these options: Stunnel Dropbear Port 443, Stunnel Squid port: 8080, What's the correct command? And how do you spoof SNI?
I tried: `ssh -o ProxyCommand='proxytunnel -v -H "SNI: youtube.com" -E -p ssl-sg1.hostip.co:443 -P fastssh.com-myusername -d %h:%p' fastssh.com-myusername@ssl-sg1.hostip.co -p 443 -ND 8080` but I can't browse the web, it refuses the connection

Comment: @Ron This is exactly what I am looking for too. I want a way to change the SNI. But SNI is a TLS extension. So I need a way to encrypt the traffic with TLS and change the SNI. I can't find a tool to do this on linux.